# quartz Scheduler in Spring

Tags: spring, cron, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

My objective is that scheduler should run on Monday, Wednesday and Friday only and should stop on the same day.

I am running a scheduler with below mentioned properties.

```
job-start=0 50 6 ? * MON,WED,FRI
job-end=0 50 8 ? * MON,WED,FRI
```

But if it is starting on Monday it is not getting stopped on Monday.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Use http://www.cronmaker.com/ to generate valid expression

Comment: what is stopping of job..check if the job is triggered at 8hrs 50 min?